# Why do I get sql error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint"

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DocGenVariable](
[userkey_sessionid] [varchar](38) NOT NULL,
[is_session] [bit] NULL,
[var_name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[var_value] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
[topic_id] [varchar](38) NOT NULL,
[resource_id] [int] NULL,
[added] [datetime] NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_DocGenVariable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [userkey_sessionid] ASC,
    [var_name] ASC,
    [topic_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sometimes (attention > sometimes) I get an error

```
"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_DocGenVariable'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DocGenVariable'.
```

when I try to add an entry into this table

```
delete from DocGenVariable where userkey_sessionid = @key_session and var_name = @var_name and topic_id = @topic_id 

if (LTRIM(RTRIM(@var_value)) <> '')
    begin
        insert into DocGenVariable(userkey_sessionid, is_session, var_name, var_value, topic_id, resource_id, added)
        values (@key_session, @is_session, @var_name, @var_value, @topic_id, @resource_id, GetDate())
    end
```

What I do first is deleting an entry which must be updated, then add a new entry.

Why do I get this constraint error?

Comment: Your insert statement is not inserting into the table you have provided the format of.  Instead of posting a picture, script out the `create table` statement and post that.

Comment: You provided a table def of DocGenAdvVariable and statement for DocGenVariable.     Those are not the same tables.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It was a wrong table, sorry. Now it must be right. Can you check it now?

Comment: And there nothing else on the table (triggers or foreign keys pointing to it) that would prevent the delete?

Answer (score 1):

Why delete then insert?  Just update it.

```
IF EXISTS(select 1 from DocGenVariable where userkey_sessionid = @key_session
```

and

```
var_name = @var_name and topic_id = @topic_id) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE ....
    END ELSE BEGIN
    INSERT ... 
END
```

Comment: Changed to UPDATE, but this did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Try [upsert](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm)

```
 using DocGenVariable target 
 using DocGenVariable source  
    on source.userkey_sessionid = @key_session     
   and source.var_name = @var_name     
   and source.topic_id = @topic_id   
   and target.userkey_sessionid = @key_session     
   and target.var_name = @var_name     
   and target.topic_id = @topic_id  
  when match 
       set target.resource_id = @resource_id 
         , target .added = GetDate()   
  when not matched then
       insert into DocGenVariable(userkey_sessionid, is_session, var_name, var_value, topic_id, resource_id, added)
       values (@key_session, @is_session, @var_name, @var_value, @topic_id, @resource_id, GetDate())
```